# how does sql.shuffle.partitions work? And how does it affect the output part files size?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on spark for quite some time. In the current project I am working with data frames and used **sql.shuffle.partitions** for optimization.

I came to see that tweaking this property affected the following,

- Running time
- Number of output files
- The size of each output file

According to my observation, I came to see that this parameter is inversely proportional to the output file size. In rare cases, not sure why, but increasing the value of this property is in turn increasing the output part files size.

---------------------------------------------------------**For example**--------------------------------------------------------

```
Scenario 1:
```

sql.shuffle.partitions : 91 **|** No. of output files : 91 **|** Size of 
each output file : **4.3 MB**

```
Scenario 2:
```

sql.shuffle.partitions : 80 **|** No. of output files : 80 **|** Size of 
each output file : **5.1 MB**

```
Scenario 3:
```

sql.shuffle.partitions : 92 **|** No. of output files : 92 **|** Size of 
each output file : **4.1 MB**

---

As you can see from the example runs above, it isn't clear on why the output file size isn't the way it is expected to be.

I tried other options like **coalesce & repartition**, which work fine, but are increasing the running time. I need the output part files to be of specific size because I need to ship them to the cloud later on, and the upload speed relies on the size of each file.

I'm trying to see if this behavior is expected or not? And why?

Thanks.

Comment: I read the data as parquet and write it out as csv @zero323

Comment: I need to control the size of each output part file. Since Coalesce & Repartition increases computation time, I am trying to see if sql.shuffle.partitions could help me achieve this. But it's being unpredictable at times.

Comment: So the sizes you provide are the maximum, average, something else? How does it look when you check total size?